# AWS DynamoDbException: The provided key element does not match the schema

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I created a DynamoDB table with two fields by following their [java sdk v2 guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/examples-dynamodb-enhanced.html);

```
PartitionKey -> Resource (String)
Field1 -> Role (String)
```

So there is no any Sort Key. And I have a very simple POJO which looks like;

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.annotations.DynamoDbBean;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.annotations.DynamoDbPartitionKey;

@DynamoDbBean
public class RoleItem {
    private String resource;
    private String role;

    @DynamoDbPartitionKey
    public String getResource() {
        return this.resource;
    };

    public void setResource(String resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return this.role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

And this is how I am testing getItem;

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhancedClient = DynamoDbEnhancedClient.create();
        DynamoDbTable<RoleItem> userRoles = enhancedClient.table("UserRoles", TableSchema.fromBean(RoleItem.class));
        Key key = Key.builder().partitionValue("FINANCE").build();
        GetItemEnhancedRequest getItemEnhancedRequest = GetItemEnhancedRequest.builder().key(key).build();
        RoleItem item = userRoles.getItem(getItemEnhancedRequest);
    }
}
```

At the end I am getting;

```
Exception in thread "main" software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DynamoDbException: The provided key element does not match the schema (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 4L424LI9BT2H2S5E9L2H0SJLE3VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG, Extended Request ID: null)
```

I couldn't find what is wrong with my example. I appreciate for your help. Thanks!

**NOTE**: Just in case I am able to achieve same operation with using [DynamoDBMapper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.html) with the same schema but using aws sdk v1 annotations. So my entity class will look like;

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBAttribute;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBHashKey;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTable;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "UserRoles")
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RoleItem {

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "Resource")
    private String resource;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Role")
    private String role;
}
```

And here is how I am executing the getItem operation;

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1).build();
        DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);
        DynamoDBQueryExpression<RoleItem> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<RoleItem>().withHashKeyValues(RoleItem.builder().resource("FINANCE").build());
        PaginatedQueryList<RoleItem> roleItems = mapper.query(RoleItem.class, queryExpression);
        RoleItem roleItem = roleItems.stream().findFirst().get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Look ok based on this code, maybe double check if this table really was created with this partition key name and without any sort key?

Comment: Hi @SudhirJonathan yes the table with correct schema exists since I also shared an example with DynamoDbMapper which works fine : )